# YoutubeService class error in android

Tags: android, api, youtube

I got this error

> E/AndroidRuntime(475): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gdata.client.youtube.YouTubeService

When I try to run Youtube data api. I have almost included all the api's, instead extra jar files but still it is giving me this error! Please give quick reply how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had updated your ADT to ADT 17 then you need not to add reference of external jar, just put that jar in a folder named "**libs**".

Comment: i have updated my ADT to 17 before. i have made user library and add all the external jars in it. and added that user library in that project . but still its giving me error

Comment: i said, you need not to add any jar now. The thing is that put all that jar in libs folder thats it.